# Does anyone know common programming conventions for Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

Does anyone know common programming conventions for Flex?

Comment: What do you mean 'against'?  Just curious ;)

Comment: @thomasrutter, English is not Joseph's first language.  "against" is often seen where one would expect "for" in novice English speakers.  I belive he means "conventions for Flex".  Although it could be "arguments against Flex" but think the first is more likely.

Comment: Thanks Sam. What I mean is "conventions for flex".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex SDK coding conventions and best practices
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions

Answer (score 0):

Back to 2007, code conventions created within company named Dclick were pretty solid:

http://blog.dclick.com.br/2007/02/13/adobe_flex_coding_guidelines_english/pt/